# how to test if a class is contained within a div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a simple pokemon card game for coding bootcamp, when the player click on any of the pokemon id's (`#pikachu`, `#squirtle` ect.) it appears in a div id called the `#playerArea`, the next pokemon id clicked should appear in the `#defenderArea`. I need to test if any of the elements that share a class of `.pokemon` are in the `#playerArea` to make the next pokemon clicked appear in the `#defenderArea`

HTML & SCRIPT BELOW (does not include css)

```
 <body>

        <header>
            <h1>Pokemon Stadium</h1>
        </header>

        <div id="selectionArea">
            <!-- pokemon cards share class but have their own IDs -->

            <div id="pikachu" class="pokemon">
                <img src="pikachu.png" height="200px" width="200px">
                <span id="pikachuHp">100</span>
                </div>


            <div id="bulbasaur" class="pokemon">
                    <img src="bulbasaur.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
                    <span id="bulbasaurHp">200</span>
                </div>

            <div id="charmander" class="pokemon">
                    <img src="charmander.png" height="200px" width="200px">
                    <span id="charmanderHp">150</span>
                </div>

             <div id="squirtle" class="pokemon">
                    <img src="squirtle.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
                    <span id="squirtleHp">120</span>
                </div>

            <div id="mario" class="pokemon">
                    <img src="mario.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
                    <span id="marioHp">300</span>
                </div>



        </div>

        <!-- Enemies are moved here upon selection-->

        <div id="defenderArea">

        </div>

        <!-- The players pokemon goes here-->

        <div id="playerArea">

                <button type="button" id="attackBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Attack</button>

        </div>

        <!-- Scripts & jQuery -->


        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pikachu').click(function() {  
        $("#pikachu").appendTo("#playerArea");
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#squirtle').click(function() {  
        $("#squirtle").appendTo("#playerArea");
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#charmander').click(function() {  
        $("#charmander").appendTo("#playerArea");
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bulbasaur').click(function() {  
        $("#bulbasaur").appendTo("#playerArea");
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mario').click(function() {  
        $("#mario").appendTo("#playerArea");
    });
});

    if ( $('#playerArea').hasClass(".pokemon") ) {
        //do something 
        alert("theres a pokemon in the playerArea");
    };
  </script>
```

should I use an if/else statement to test the playerArea or should I use an if/else to see if an ID was clicked?

Comment: Side note, you could combine all those document ready methods into a single one.

Comment: 1. You don't need to wrap each individual click event in its own `$(document).ready( ... )`, you can just have one wrap the whole thing. 2. I'd suggest working out the logistics of which pokemon goes to which side based on an object, array, variables, etc, instead of simply relying on the DOM each and every time. Not only would it be a bit cleaner, but you can avoid repeated expensive DOM lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with one click handler (based on a good selector), use `this` to know which pokemon was clicked and use a ternary operator (again *within* the click handler) to decide where to append it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectionArea .pokemon').click(function() {  
        $(this).appendTo($('#playerArea .pokemon').length ? "#defenderArea" : "#playerArea");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//find a count of how many pokemon are children of the playerArea
if( $('#playerArea').find('.pokemon').length > 0 ) {
  //put pokemon in defender area
}
```